# Unable to import soap-npm module with webpack 4 and babel 7

Tags: javascript, webpack, soap, babeljs

I've updated `Webpack (v4.34.0)` and `Babel (v7.4.5)` in an old `Framework7 (v4.4.3)` / `Vue.js (v2.6.10)` project.

I need to use [`node-soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) library as a soap client in my browser, but when run the code compiled by webpack, this library it's value is **undefined**

```js
import soap from 'soap'
console.log('Soap Library Imported: ', soap)
Soap Library Imported: undefined
```

All works fine with `axios` library.

```js
import axios from 'axios'
console.log('Axios Library Imported: ', axios)
Axios Library Imported: ƒ wrap() {...}
```

I think I'm having a module import trouble with `babel`, but I'm figuring out where the problem could be.

Thank for your help.

---

**.babelrc**

```js
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "modules": "auto",
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [
          "Android >= 5",
          "IOS >= 9.3",
          "Edge >= 15",
          "Safari >= 9.1",
          "Chrome >= 49",
          "Firefox >= 31",
          "Samsung >= 5",
        ],
      },
    }],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-vue-jsx",
    // "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
  ],
}
```

**webpack.config.js** (extract)

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: env,
  node: {
    setImmediate: false,
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty', 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          resolvePath('src'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7-vue'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/template7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/dom7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/ssr-window'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/soap'),
        ],
      },
   },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is happening is `node-soap` doesn't have a default export (see [`soap.js`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/soap.ts)) and you are not importing any of its named exports, so they get dropped during compilation by webpack's [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and all you get is an empty chunk (you could confirm this by inspecting the bundle generated by webpack).

Try importing the `node-soap` methods directly as named exports, e.g. [`createClient`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soapcreateclienturl-options-callback---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path):

```
import { createClient } from 'soap'
```

Comment: Thank you @sdgluck!
It works.
I had this problem only after having updated webpack and babel 7. 
In my previous code, with `vue-cli`, I was usual to import `import soap from 'soap'` without any problem. Do you know what could be the reason?

Anyhow, thank you for the links you give in the answers, they help me a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: You're welcome :-) What version of Babel did you upgrade from?

Comment: I used `babel` inside [`@vue/cli-plugin-babel`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v3.7.0) v3.7.0. It seems [`"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/v3.7.0/package.json). But I got to be honest... I don't know yet very well the implementation of webpack and babel, vue-cli does the job for me. I need to study more about it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To use listen (server), this worked for me:

```
import * as soap from 'soap';
soap.listen(...);
```